# Force TR CSS over TD

Tags: css, html-table

I understand that by definition, TD's CSS definition overrides TR's CSS.  Is there a way to do so otherwise?

My situation is as follows.  I have rows of information.  In one particular column, the text is in Green.  However, I want to "lock" a row, the whole row will be Grey regardless.  Is there a way to do this?

I'm trying to achieve this via !important but its not working.

Sample code:

CSS

```
.locked {
    color: #6D6D6D !important;
}
.count {
    color: #08C420;
}
```

HTML

```
<tr class="unlocked">
    <td class="count">10,000</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="locked">
<td class="count">20,000</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Right now, all cells with class count are showing green.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hierarchiy?

```
.locked > .count {
    color: #6D6D6D;
}
.unlocked > .count {
    color: #08C420;
}
```

[see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnBFN)

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem. Is this compatible on all browsers?

Comment: its a css2 selector, should work in all css2 capable browsers: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2)